# How to persist grouping settings on an Ajax bound Telerik MVC Grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax, telerik

I am looking for an example of how to persist grouping settings on an Ajax bound Telerik ASP .NET MVC grid. What I am trying to do is set the grid display back to it's previous settings if someone navigates away to a detail screen and then navigates back to the grid. I currently have both sorting and filtering working but the grouping settings is giving me trouble. I have reviewed several posts on the telerik forums and have not found a good solution. My current process saves the grid settings to the session and then re-constitutes them when the grid .aspx page is loaded via the onLoad Event that fires prior to the ajax call that loads the grid data.

```
function onLoad()
{
    $('#DebtLoanGrid').find('.t-no-data td').text('Loading Data...');
    var grid = $('#DebtLoanGrid').data('tGrid');
    grid.orderBy = "<%= ViewData["DebtLoanGrid-orderBy"] %>";
    grid.filterBy = "<%= ViewData["DebtLoanGrid-filterBy"] %>";
    grid.groupBy = "<%= ViewData["DebtLoanGrid-groupBy"] %>";
}
```

I am open to any examples or suggestions.

Comment: Did you get any success we also need this feature

Comment: Sorry., I have not been able to solve the issue. I just checked my code and the "grid.groupBy" line is commented out.

Answer (score 0):

I have discussion thread on telerik forum get it solved Please have a look at [this](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-mvc/grid/preserve-grid-state-between-pages.aspx) thread